# How should I quit my job?

Tags: quitting

I started work with a kitchen design company straight out of school. My first boss was a narcissistic pig, who at times could be inappropriate and creepy towards the girls in the office. I was there for 3 years before I cracked and knew I had to leave.

Luckily, one of our suppliers reps got in touch with me. He was taking on a kitchen design showroom a half hour bus journey from where I lived. He asked if I would be interested in doing the administration work for them. When he explained the ins and outs, it all sounded great, so I took the chance (no contract was signed and I had to go self employed).His wife was the manager and he was the designer/salesman. I was to do some of the designs but mostly admin work. It started off great, they seemed great.

It's been seven months now and although we get on fine, I barely see either of them in the office. They work from home most days, my "manager" is only part time (6 hours a week) in the office and the "designer" who asked me to join them is still a rep for another company based abroad. So you're lucky if he is even in the country!

My main concern is that since I started working in that office, my mental health has severely deteriorated. It's so bad I'm medicated for anxiety/depression and I think it's down to being alone, boxed in, without any human interaction for five days a week.

Since seeking help I've applied for college, which I start in a few months time. So I've been preparing to tell my manager I'm leaving for a while now. I know that normally you would hand in a two weeks notice, but with being self employed and having no contract, I'm thinking of just leaving right away.

I have enough money saved to last me a few months without work, until I go to college and start my placement.
What should I do ?

Comment: Always put your health first. Do you want to leave? Could you do the work remotely yourself and find somewhere nearer to you that has other people, a co-working space for example?

Comment: Dear Mr so n so, I am informing you that from xxxx date I will no longer be in your employ. Regards Hometree.

Comment: Saying that your "boss was a narcissistic pig, who at times could be inappropriate and creepy towards the girls in the office" is unlikely to go down well. You are by all means entitled to that feeling, but I encourage you to not express it toward a potential employer or client. Put yourself in their position: What guarantees do they have that you won't turn around and refer to them similarly down the road? The standard way of phrasing it is about looking for a change in work environment, responsibilities, and professional growth. Everyone knows what it means, but it's not offensive to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, good job on putting your health first. Your work should never take priority over your health.

Secondly, try and leave without burning any bridges. The best way to quit is cleanly and professionally... no matter what your relationship or feelings about the company are.

I'd suggest giving your notice by hand (or by email, if you never see them) and hold out for the two weeks if you're able to. If they ask you why, you can be completely honest and say it's for your health or say that you're preparing for college - especially if you're financially ready for it.

**(I'm not a doctor, so please see one and get their advice!)**

Good luck!